# coinbase oauth authorization returns html, how to integrate with my web-app

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, coinbase-api

So, I am creating a web-application that works with coinbase.  The front-end is a standard static page with html and jquery, this is very vanilla.  The back-end is a separate web-app that is made with Spring 5 and has a bunch of RESTful web-services.

I go to my login.html and I login.  That means I send the username/password back to my login Spring Controller, and I get an access token sent back to the UI.  I put that in a cookie, and then I reload a new page with a big fat authorize button on that page.

That button does an AJAX call to my Spring RESTful controller passing in the token, as i wanted to make that endpoint secure which works great.

On the back-end (or middle-ware), I am making a RESTful call to Coinbase to start the process of Oauth2 authentication.   I read in my client-id from a properties file, I pass in the redirectURI, and a state.  All this works great, it gets to coinbase, and the response is HTML.   I pass that back to my client, the front-end, and I have this HTML which is the coinbase authorization page.

Now here is where it gets dicey ... I am a back-end person, so I can make that RESTful call on the back-end with no issue.  I get the HTML, which is supposed to be the AUTHORIZE page to allow the user to let my web-app be used with their coinbase account.  I get HTML and now I am at a loss as the correct way to display this html on my page or a new page.  This is my lack of javascript and jquery knowledge.

The AJAX code in my authorize.js looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/myapp-be/api/coinbase/authorization',
        headers : {'mytoken' : mytoken},
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
           success: function(response) {
               $("html").html(response);
           }
    });
```

Is this the correct way to go?

I absolutely can take the coinbase call put it in my browser, and it pops up the Coinbase Authorization dialog box easily.  If I authorize, putting in my username/password, I am sent to the callback page which I passed in as the callback redirect uri.

But, it was my understanding, that we did not want to expose the client-id to anyone.  That is why my back-end does it, and we just return the HTML.  So, I am a held up here.
With my current code, I get many Javascript errors, and I just know this isn't the way to go.  I get a lot of CORS issues, and when I try to authorize I get an error that it can't get to the correct page.

How would one correctly call the Coinbase authorization API.  Their documentation page:
https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/integrating
Shows in Step 1:

```
GET 
https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL&state=SECURE_RANDOM&scope=wallet:accounts:read
```

So, sadly, I am a little confused on the best way to solve this issue.
Either I make this GET call from the client exposing client-id, if that is ok?
Or, I can figure out the correct way to display the HTML coming back for the Coinbase Authorization page?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's been a very long while since I have had to do any UI work.  I've never had to worry about cross-scripting or iframe issues or security issues relating to the front=end (UI).

From what I am gathering, pulling HTML from a third-party website onto a div, or into an iframe on my web-site is not the best plan.  I can tell you that even though I did pull the HTML into the web-page on my site, there was a ton of javascript errors and CORS issues.

Ultimately, my ajax call to my middle-ware was changed to just pull back the coinbase authorization URL.  A simple windows redirect and there I was on the coinbase web-site as it should be.  Once I did the authorization, then I was redirected back to my redirect link that I told Coinbase to do.

So, getting the link and doing a simple redirect worked.  Loading HTML from a third-party site into my web-pages did not.   Lesson learned!

Thanks!  Hope this helps someone else out.